# How do I specific ya jQuery selector that says "starts with a string and contains a character"

Tags: jquery

What is the right selector format for me to get a list of elements starting with a string and containing a specific charater? I know I can use `^` to find match the start of the string but how can I do that and filter it based on those containing say a "-" character?

For example, I have the following:

```
$('tr[id^="' + sectionName + '"]').hide();
```

Any element that starts with the value of sectionName will be hidden. I want to take this one level further and filter out those elements with a "-" within the id attributes value.

Comment: What elements, what string, searching attributes, or actual text from the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an [attribute starts-with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector, like you mentioned in your question, along with an "[attribute-contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)" selector:

```
var elem = $("[id^='something'][id*='-']");
```

You probably want to make that selector a bit more efficient by making it more specific, but your question does not have enough detail for me to help. For example, provide the tag name:

```
var elem = $("div[id^='something'][id*='-']");
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div[id^="red"][id*="-"]')
```

should match

```
<div id='red1-1' />
<div id='red1-2' />
```

and shouldn't match

```
<div id='blue1-1' />
<div id='red161' />
```